# SVN: best practice for versioning you live server?

Tags: svn, version-control, versioning

I want to track all changes on a Typo3 live server via SVN. This works well so far but since I've updated an extention with the build in extention manager, I'm getting a SVN error:

```
svn: 'ext/realurl' is not a working copy directory
```

This is because the folder was replaced compleatly by the update process. Are there any best practices to handle such changes? Would GIT be a better fit for such a scenario?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You must answer on questions (me - and yourself) "**What** I store in repo" and "**For which task** I use repository". Maybe old good FS-backup + DB-backup will be better. I, supposedly, know nothing about Typo3, but see you methodology as very much mistaken in a set of points

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Extension Manager deletes the existing extension folder and replaces it with the newer one. That means, your ".svn" directories get deleted.

Best practice is to first do your Updates (better all your File-Changes) manually in a testing enviroment, commit the changes and then do a SVN-Update on your Live Server.

Answer (score 0):

If this directory is a **sub-folder of your working copy**, you may simply use Subversion > v1.7.

This way, subversion will store only one `.svn` folder at the top of the working copy (instead of one in each folder) , so even if subfolder is re-created, SVN will not send an error.